Scala: first class function place holder syntax
I was coding in Scala and I came across this issue. The following code compiles just fine:
val speed: (Int, Int) => Float = _.toFloat / _

and by the same logic I thought this would too, but it does not
val printSpace: String => Unit = print(_ + " ")

Could anyone explain me why?
I tried to change it to
val printSpace: String => Unit = s => print(s +" ")


which works but I do not understand why the first version does not since it specifies that _ is a string

The first version expands to this: print(s => s + " ") meaning you are printing a function rather than a string and that you didn't define any function at all. My personal advice, don't use the placeholder syntax for anything other than the very simple use cases like map(_.foo) or reduce(_ + _). Everything slightly more complex than that can lead into weird errors and less readability than just writing a normal lambda.

That explains! Thanks

val printSpace: String => Unit = ((_: String) + " ") andThen print
val printSpace: String => Unit = (print _) compose (_ + " ")
